# Select multiple columns from Linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two tables. Customer and CustomerBenefits.

Fields in each table

```
Customer - ID, Name, Address, Country etc
CUstomerBenefits -  CustomerID, BenefitID (Both IDs have a relation to their relevant tables)
```

I am trying to list the customers and get the Benefit Details

```
    IEnumerable<CustomerBenefit> GetData = from c in MyContext.CUstomerBenefits
                                                   where c.CustomerId == UserId & c.Active = true
                                                   orderby c.CustomerBenefit.BenType descending
                                                   select new {???? };
```

For the Select, Ive tried

```
select new {c.Benefit.Name }
```

but get the error

*Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

If i change `IEnumerable<CustomerBenefit>` to `IEnumerable<dynamic>` i get no errors but when the data is bound to my gridview i get the error that a field is not found.

How could i keep `IEnumerable<CustomerBenefit>` and select the columns i require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> CUstomerBenefits -  CustomerID, BenefitID (Both IDs have a relation to
>   their relevant tables)

I interpret this as meaning that there is a table `CustomerBenefit` that contains, well, benefits and that the `CUstomerBenefits` table in turn is a link between the customer and the benefits. And now you want to get a list of all the benefits that a specific customer has?

This should do the trick:

```
IEnumerable<CustomerBenefit> GetData =
    from c in MyContext.CUstomerBenefits
    where c.CustomerId == UserId && c.Active == true
    orderby c.CustomerBenefit.BenType descending
    select c.CustomerBenefit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use: `select c` to get all of the column values or:

`select new CustomerBenefit {CustomerID = c.CustomerID};` etc

Answer (score 0):

```
var HOQuotePremiums = (from holoc in objRes.ResHO.HOLocations
                                               from cst in ((HOLocation)holoc).HOBuildings
                                               select new
                                               {
                                                   RequestId = cst.HOPremium.RequestId,
                                                   BasePremium = Convert.ToInt32(cst.HOPremium.BasePremium),
                                                   PersonalLiabilityPremium = cst.HOPremium.PersonalLiabilityPremium,
                                                   MedicalPaymentPremium = cst.HOPremium.MedicalPaymentPremium,
                                                   FinalPremium = objRes.ResHO.FinalPremium,
                                                   WithoutAOPDeductibleFinalPremium = cst.HOPremium.WithoutAOPDeductibleFinalPremium,
                                                   SubTotalPremium = objRes.ResHO.FinalPremiumWithoutFeeTax,
                                                   LocationID = holoc.LocationID,
                                                   BuildingID = cst.BuildingID,
                                                   IsMinimumPremium = cst.HOPremium.IsMinimumPremium,
                                                   MinimumPremium = cst.HOPremium.MinimumPremium,
                                                   SubTotalPremiumWithoutMinimumPremium = cst.HOPremium.SubTotalPremiumWithoutMinimumPremium,
                                                   FinalRate=cst.HOPremium.FinalRate,
                                               }).ToList();
```

Please try this .